# Disable softkey rotation in android device

Tags: android, rotation, screen-orientation, android-orientation, softkeys

when changing device orientation softkey also change to top and bottom of the device. How can i disable it and fix to the softkey bar to bottom of the device in android application.

[image]

Comment: Workaround can be hiding android navigation bar and designing your own in-app

Comment: thanx.. ya.. but hiding the softkeys may effect for the app. then i transparent it. the problem is detect rotation on softkey.